# String conversion to date in Dataweave

Tags: mule, esb, date-format, string-conversion, dataweave

My input is a `.csv` format file with a date of birth column which contains strings such as

```
Aug-03-2015
```

I want to change this coloumn to a date (if not possible then at least to another string) format as below

```
03-08-2015
```

. 
Tried the logic suggested by RyanCarter. I have now tried using

```
Birthday:$.DOB as :date {format : "MMM-dd-yyyy"} as :string {format: "dd/MM/yyyy"}
```

where DOB is a string column in the .csv input. But i got the below exception.

```
Message               : Exception while executing: 
DOB:$.DOB as :date {format : "MMM-dd-yyyy"} as :string {format: "dd/MM/yyyy"}
      ^

Cannot coerce a :string to a :date, caused by :Text 'NOV-03-1992' could not be parsed at index 0
Type                  : com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
********************************************************************************

Exception stack is:
1. Cannot coerce a :string to a :date, caused by :Text 'NOV-03-1992' could not be parsed at index 0 

(com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException)

com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.LocalDateTypeCoercionValue:30 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
DOB:$.DOB as :date {format : "MMM-dd-yyyy"} as :string {format: "dd/MM/yyyy"}
      ^
Cannot coerce a :string to a :date, caused by :Text 'NOV-03-1992' could not be parsed at index 0 (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)

com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler:166 (null)

********************************************************************************

Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException: Cannot coerce a :string to a :date, caused by :Text 'NOV-03-1992' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a date firt using the date format, then back to a String using the second date format:

```
varOutput: 'Aug-03-2015'  as :date {format : "MMM-dd-yyyy"} as :string {format: "dd/MM/yyyy"}
```

Comment: Instead of using 'Aug-03-2015' directly i have tried extracting the value from the input metadata as $.DOB where DOB is the column name in input. I got a "Cannot coerce a :string to a :date" error. Instead of writing the string in data weave how do i pickup the value from the input?

Comment: Its probably not in the correct format. Can you post the stack trace with the date its trying to parse?

Comment: Added the exception stack trace in the question.

Comment: My bad. I have now changed the input to "Nov-03-1992" and it works . Thanks for the hlep :)